# In jsTree plugin how can we search nodes by node id instead of node name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree, jstree-search

The default search plugin in JSTree is search through node name pattern matching,

Can we be able to search through nodes ID rather than nodes name ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure! And you don't need a plugin for that.
Simply search for an element with that id and optionally select found node

```
$('#tree').jstree("select_node", $('#'+searchedNodeId));
```

See example:  [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/6r3fxa8a/)